# Integrating surface area of a sphere with a cylinder “drilled” out

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spheres

Given a sphere with radius 30cm and there is a hole of radius 3cm.

How can I complete the question in a cylindrical coordinate?

My attempt:

$Surface Area=\int{\int_D{\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}}} dA$

I don't know how to find out the area.

Comment: I would like to ask about the upper limit and lower limit for the integral. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming the cap.is missing one can consider s surface of revolution. Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586722/loss-of-height-rate-in-a-half-sphere/3586755#3586755 is useful.

Comment: draw a cross section and apply Pythagora's on $R, r$ and find the angle limits

Comment: 0<=theta<=2pi how about r?

Comment: Astonishingly the volume of the remaining "ring" solely depends on its height, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658004/remaining-volume-of-a-sphere/658215#658215

Comment: I need to calculate surface area instead of volume.

Comment: did you draw a sketch of the cross section ? do you see the angle $\alpha = arcsin(r/R)$ ?

Comment: sphere:
x^2+y^2+z^2=30^2
cylinder:
x^2+y^2=3^2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347180/surface-area-of-sphere-with-cylindrical-cutout

I tried to follow his way to do so but his way is not correct